# What is the acceptable memory size consumed by j2ME applications?

Tags: memory, java-me, size

I developed a J2ME application for s60 device. I used the memory monitor of sun wireless toolkit
to monitor memory size consumed during the execution of my application. I found that
memory size consumed reaches 126 KB. I wanted to know what is the standard memory size
consumed by J2ME applications? In other words, what is the optimum or acceptable memory size consumed
by the execution of J2ME applications. In order to compare and evaluate my application's
memory consumption according to standards.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there are any standards concerning memory consumption. Memory consumption depends on the nature of the app and amount of data it works with. There are too major concerns regarding memory - running of out it and/or too much GC activity (too frequent and/or taking too much time).

Given the fact that heap size is typically at least 1 MB on non-smartphones, and on S60 heap size is limited only by free memory, then with your 126 kB (top consumption as you say) you are more than fine and quite far from OutOfMemoryError :), and *I guess* there is also low GC activity because only a small part of heap is used and thus there is little pressure to run gc...